# Why is grep Failing to Find Matches on my Groovy Dependencies?

Tags: groovy, buildr

Does anyone know why the following code returns an empty array? Thanks.

```
groovyc_deps = Buildr::Groovy::Groovyc.dependencies
groovy_jar = groovyc_deps.grep /.*groovy.*\.jar/
p groovy_jar # => []
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `Groovyc.dependencies` returns an array of `Artifact`, not Strings.

Try the following,

```
groovyc_deps = Buildr::Groovy::Groovyc.dependencies
groovy_jar = groovyc_deps.select { |a| a.to_s =~ /.*groovy.*\.jar/ }
```

which converts artifacts to string before matching against the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I *assumed* that the array was populated with `Strings`.